# Mysql commands are not getting execute on the User class

Tags: php

I have the following classes which are the connect (db) and the users class (User). When trying to run an sql statement from the users class I get the following error:

[09-Aug-2022 10:39:11 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in CustomerCare.class.php on line 69

```
namespace CustomerCare;
class db
{
    public $db_host;
    public $db_usermame;
    public $db_password;
    public $db_database;        

    public function __construct()
    {   
        $this->db_host      = "...";
        $this->db_username  = "...";
        $this->db_password  = "...";
        $this->db_database  = "...";
        
        $this->mysqli = new \mysqli($this->db_host, $this->db_username, $this->db_password, $this->db_database);    
        
        if ($this->mysqli->connect_errno) {
            die("error...".$this->mysqli->connect_error);
        }

        $this->mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
        return $this->mysqli;
    }
}

class User
{
    private static $_id;
    private static $_firstname;
    private static $_lastname;
    private static $_email;
    private static $_entityId;

    public function __construct($_mysqli){
        $this->db       = $_mysqli->mysqli;
    }
    
    public function getId()             {   return self::$_id;          }
    public function getFirstname()      {   return self::$_firstname;   }
    public function getLastname()       {   return self::$_lastname;    }
    public function getEmail()          {   return self::$_email;       }
    public function getEntityId()       {   return self::$_entityId;    }

    public function setId($var)         {   self::$_id          =   $var;   }
    public function setFirstname($var)  {   self::$_firstname   =   $var;   }
    public function setLastname($var)   {   self::$_lastname    =   $var;   }
    public function setEmail($var)      {   self::$_email       =   $var;   }
    public function setEntityId($var)   {   self::$_entityId    =   $var;   }

    public function ComboBoxUsers($ei,$user)
    {
        $key= "blablabla";
        $sql = "call new_getUsers('{$ei}','{$key}');";
        $rs =  $this->db->query($sql);

        $output = ""; $selected = "";
        if ($rs->num_rows >0)
        {
            while ($record = mysqli_fetch_array($rs,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            {
                if ($record['userEmail'] == $user) {
                    $selected = 'Selected';
                } else {
                    $selected = "";
                }
                $output .=  "<option value='{$record['userEmail']}' {$selected}>";
                $output .=      "{$record['userLastname']} {$record['userFirstname']} {$record['title']}";
                $output .=  "</option>";
            }
        }
        return $output;
      
    }
}
```

Do someone have an idea why the mysqli commands and not getting read?

Comment: error on line 69 is referring to  $rs =  $this->db->query($sql);

Comment: How are you creating the instance of your `User` class?

Comment: from the TicketEdit.php I do:
$db = new db();
$user = new User($db);

Comment: Your `db` constructor return `$this->mysqli`, and in `User` you are expecting that to have a `mysqli` property, again? This should be just `$this->db = $_mysqli;` in the User constructor.

Comment: @CBroe the return statement in the ctor just gets neglected anyway no? It is strange though to create a wrapper around `mysqli` and then don't do anything with it

Comment: same problem: error on line         $rs =  $this->db->query($sql);

Comment: What does `var_dump($this->db)` return?

Comment: The Initialization of the classes are here below:
include "backend/classes/CustomerCare.class.php";
                
$db         =   new CustomerCare\db();
$ticket     =   new CustomerCare\Ticket($db);
$user       =   new CustomerCare\User($db);
$client     =   new CustomerCare\Client($db);
$entity     =   new CustomerCare\Entity($db);
$group      =   new CustomerCare\Group($db);
$contact    =   new CustomerCare\Contact($db);
$street     =   new CustomerCare\Street($db);
$town       =   new CustomerCare\Town($db);

Comment: [09-Aug-2022 11:29:57 Europe/Berlin] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method CustomerCare\db::query() in CustomerCare.class.php:65

Comment: object(mysqli)#2 (19) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(1) ["client_info"]=> string(79) "mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: b396954eeb2d1d9ed7902b8bae237b287f21ad9e $" ["error"]=> string(52) "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" ["error_list"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["errno"]=> int(2014) ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "HY000" ["error"]=> string(52) "Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now" } }

Comment: I included the $this->db->close(); after previous sql statement execution but still having this error:
mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli
mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli

Comment: @user3448324, start with the constructor. Anything you [return from it will be discarded](https://3v4l.org/u4llM). If there’s anything you want to keep in the constructor you need to use the class’s properties. The alternative is to use an instance or static method somehow instead.

Comment: So why is another method in the Ticketing class working fine?

Comment: I solved this problem by using PDO connection and statement. So the problem was something related to MYSQLI.

Comment: Based on what you’ve posted as an answer, you were using a `connect` method for PDO which _can_ return something and a `__construct` method for mysqli which cannot return anything

Answer (score 0):

changed the database connection using the following class:

```php
    class Dbh 
    {
        protected function connect()
        {
            try {
                $username = "....";
                $password = "....";

                $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=....',$username,$password);
                return $dbh;
            }
            catch (PDOException $e) {
                print "Error!: ".$e->getMessage()."<br/>";
                die();
            }
        }
    }
```

and also changed methods PDO statements.